# C# base class for a 'group' of generic classes

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there something like a base class for generic classes?

I want something like this

```
public class MyCollection<T> where T : MyBaseObject 
{
  void Add(MyBaseObject obj)
  {
    /* cast to T and insert */
  }

  int Count
  {
    get
    {
      /* count something */
    }
  }
}

public class MyCollectionCollection
{
  Dictionary<Type, MyCollection> collections = new Dictionary<Type, MyCollection>();

  Add(MyBaseObject obj)
  {
    collections[obj.GetType()].Add(obj);
  }
}
```

`MyCollectionCollection` contains (known) subclasses of `MyBaseObject`, which are stored in type-specific collections.

`Dictionary<Type, MyCollection>` doesn't work. I have to define an interface `IMyCollection`. But than I have to put every method into `MyCollection<T>` and into `IMyCollection`, which seems a bit redundant. And I have to write a getter/setter to replace fields like `MyCollection<T>.Count`, which seems bloated.

**Edit:**
`public void Add(T obj)` in `MyCollection<T>` was my first attempt, but I don't know, how to use that in `MyCollectionCollection`. `Dictionary<Type, MyCollection> collections` doesn't work (CS0305). I need a base class for all `MyCollection<T>` there, which has `Add(T element)`.

Comment: You don't have to "cast to T and insert". Your generic constraint enforces that for you... I don't quite understand what you're aiming for. Can you rephrase your requirement?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - if he implements the class properly and uses `void Add(T obj)`.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. What's wrong with `void Add(T obj)` ?

Comment: @Enigmativity Indeed - that's what I was getting at :)

Comment: Instead of base classes try thinking of Interfaces!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are looking for either, but if you are looking to have something like a `List<BaseObject>` and then find all of the items that are actually ThingThatInheritsFromBaseObject, you can use the `OfType<ThingThatInheritsFromBaseObject>()` filter.  Add a `using System.Linq;` statement at the top and then calling `myList.OfType<ThingThatInheritsFromBaseObject>()` will return only the list items that match.  If that works for you, then you don't need to go through the trouble of putting the items in all those different collections.

Comment: I want to store the objects in different collections, because I will often request all objects of a certain type.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this:

```
public class MyCollection<T> where T : MyBaseObject 
{
    public void Add(MyBaseObject obj)
    {
        /* cast to T and insert */
    }
}
```

And then I have this:

```
public class ConcreteA : MyBaseObject
{
}

public class ConcreteB : MyBaseObject
{
}
```

I can write this code:

```
var myCollection = new MyCollection<ConcreteA>();
var b = new ConcreteB();
myCollection.Add(b);
```

Which would clearly fail the `/* cast to T and insert */` requirement.

If you implement it like this it works:

```
public class MyCollection<T> where T : MyBaseObject 
{
    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        /* no need to cast to T, just insert */
    }
}
```